# Combine php cookie check with request uri

Tags: php, cookies, request, include, uri

I'm looking for a way to combine this working script with another check: request uri ?=en or ?=nl. I need this because a php include according to the active language cookie (nl or en) doesn't change immediately after you press the language button. The buttons bring you to [].php?=en - which in fact just refreshes the page. To see the php include in the correct language, you need to refresh the page one more time. Thats a problem. Can anybody help me?

```
<?php
if( $_COOKIE['lang'] == "nl"){
    include ('statement_nl.php');
}
else{
    include ('statement_en.php');
}
?>
```

**EDIT:**

After a few hours of puzzling I found a way to make it work:

```
<?php

if( $_COOKIE['lang'] == "nl"){
     include ('statement_nl.php'); } 
else if (isset($_GET["lang"]) AND ($_GET["lang"]=="nl")) { 
     include ('statement_nl.php'); }  
else if (isset($_GET["lang"]) AND ($_GET["lang"]=="en")) { 
     include ('statement_en.php'); }   
else{
     include ('statement_en.php'); } 
 ?>
```

Comment: You can get the query string using this code: `parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $vars);`. Then you can add the check condition.

Comment: Thank you! I made it work :).